# OpenCV error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently in Windows 10, using Python 3 and cv2.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 1) 
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

But I get this error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-177-540d1ccc2ece>", line 6, in <module>
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

error: OpenCV(3.4.4) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please check: 1) If the image exists in the path provided 2) if the image is loaded correctly(`print(img)`).

Comment: Path is correct. I print(img), it returns None.

Comment: If you are getting `None`, this means the image has not loaded correctly. Please check the image path and confirm again. I've tested with my own test image and `print(img)` should return an array of pixels for the image.

Comment: That's weird, I have successfully installed opencv-python-4.0.0.21 and import cv2, I don't know why it can't read image properly.

Comment: Are you sure `test.jpg` is in the same directory as your script? Check the image as well.

Comment: I find the reason. OpenCV imread does not handle non-ascii characters on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @amanb. OpenCV imread does not handle non-ascii characters on Windows. For the image which has foreign language or non-ascii characters. Please try with the following code:

```
def cv_imread(file_path):
    cv_img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromfile(file_path, dtype=np.uint8), -1)
    return cv_img
file_path = './Test.jpg'
img = cv_imread(file_path)
print(img)
```

Comment: To work with your function, remember to import numpy: `import numpy as np`